# VB.net How do I tell my program to wait until it has completed a task before it carries out the next one?

Tags: vb.net

I have a program that is works fine one minute but as soon as my internet connection slows it stops working.

This is because I have everything set by timers.

I have tried slowing the intervals and still it messes up from time to time.

There must be a way for the program to wait until it has completed one task and then automatically carry out the next task instead of hooking the next task up to a timer.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
    WebBrowser1.navigate("http://www.google.com") 
    [IF COMPLETED THEN MOVE ON TO NEXT TASK] 
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("gbqfba").InvokeMember("click")
```

I'm pulling my hair out trying to work it figure it out lol

Comment: see the `DocumentCompleted` event; events are rather a key thing in Win/NET programming.

Answer (score 1):

The code in that method should end at the `Navigate` call.  When the `WebBrowser` has finished loading the specified page, it will raise its `DocumentCompleted` event.  You handle that event and process the page in the event handler.  You can then call `Navigate` to load the next page and the process continues.  By handling the event you don't have to care how long it takes to load the page.  you know that you'll process it the moment it is loaded; not sooner, not later.

Comment: Hi and thanks for helping, I tried to study this subject before but I was stumped when it comes to using it more than once in the same code. How would it handle multiple events is what i think I'm trying to ask haha

Answer (score 0):

```
Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000) ' 1000 milliseconds is 1 second
```

Looking at your code, why not use the events?

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("gbqfba").InvokeMember("click")
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah this is where I got confused before, how would I then go on to the next task? because webbrowser1_documentcompleted would have already been used. 

I'm not very good at explaining myself lol, with timers they are seperate right? like timer1, timer2 etc. but how would I use WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted more than once?

Comment: No problem. Basically with events, whatever code you have there will trigger on that particular event. Try putting something simple there, such as MessageBox.Show("Event triggered") so that you may see when the code is being executed. You can always include conditional statements in the event.